# Expanding $\left(\sum_{r=1, r\neq i}^mT_r\right)\left(\sum_{s=1, s\neq i}^mT_s^{-1}\right).$

Tags: sequences-and-series

*I'm pretty sure that this has been asked before but I can't find it anywhere. All my search results are clouded by GCSE revision on expanding brackets.*

### The Problem:

> Fix $m\in\Bbb N$ and $i\in\overline{1, m}$. Expand and simplify $$\left(\sum_{r=1,\\ r\neq i}^mT_r\right)\left(\sum_{s=1,\\ s\neq i}^mT_s^{-1}\right)$$ for non-zero complex numbers $(T_j)_{j\in\overline{1, m}}$.

### My Attempt:

We have

$$\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{r=1,\\ r\neq i}^mT_r\right)\left(\sum_{s=1,\\ s\neq i}^mT_s^{-1}\right)&=1+T_1T_2^{-1}+\dots +T_1T_{i-1}^{-1}+0+T_1T_{i+1}^{-1}+\dots +T_1T_m^{-1} \\
&+T_2T_1^{-1}+1+\dots +T_2T_{i-1}^{-1}+0+T_2T_{i+1}^{-1}+\dots +T_2T_m^{-1} \\
&+ \\
&\vdots \\
&+T_{i-1}T_1^{-1}+\dots +T_{i-1}T_{i-2}^{-1}+1+0+T_{i-1}T_{i+1}^{-1}+\dots +T_{i-1}T_m^{-1} \\
&+T_{i+1}T_1^{-1}+\dots +T_{i+1}T_{i-1}^{-1}+0+1+T_{i+1}T_{i+2}^{-1}+\dots +T_{i
+1}T_m^{-1} \\
&+ \\
&\vdots \\
&+T_mT_1^{-1}+\dots +T_mT_{i-1}^{-1}+0+T_mT_{i+1}^{-1}+\dots +1 \\
&=(m-1)+X,
\end{align}$$

but I don't know what that $X$ should be.

I expect to see binomial coefficients in there.

### Added Complication:

I would prefer not to relabel. This problem arose in my research, where it's important to keep track on the subscripts.

*Please help* :)

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: You may as well assume you have a sequence of $m-1$ nonzero complex numbers (just omit the $i$th one) and then forget about the extra restriction on the indices. Then write the product as $\sum_r \sum_s T_r/T_s$ and proceed from there.

Comment: @YakovShklarov Ah, see, that first thing - relabeling and omitting the $i$th term - won't work for me, because in what I'm doing it's important to keep track of the indices; I should have mentioned that in the above. I'm sorry. I'll add it now.

Comment: @YakovShklarov Nevermind, I see what to do now.

Comment: Not the indices, the subscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler than I thought:

$$X=\sum_{r=1,\\ r\neq i}^m\sum_{s=1,\\ s\neq i,\\ s\neq r}^m\frac{T_r}{T_s}.$$